# ErrorException: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument

Tags: php, json, utf-8

This issue is occurred in my server but I can't reproduce this. My code for this as follows

```
$data = [
            'param1' => urlencode($param1),
            'param2'  => urlencode($param2)
        ];
echo json_encode($data);
```

$param1 and $param2 is taken by query string
ex http://mydomain?param1=param1&param2=param2

I tried to reproduce this with applying non utf-8 characters but could not reproduce. Please help me to reproduce this.
sample urls I tested.

[http://mydomain?param1=parÃÂam1&param2=param2](http://mydomain?param1=par%C3%83%C3%82am1&param2=param2)

Comment: `urlencode` should always return an ASCII string, so I can't see how your code would ever produce an "Invalid UTF-8 sequence" error. I suspect there's something else at play.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this without encoding the parameter and I hard coded parameter as follows but still could not reproduce this issue.
$param1 = "À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö × Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö";
$data = [ 'param1' => $param1];
echo json_encode($data);

Comment: @nwellnhof you are correct thank you very much for the help actually this issue was not occurred because of these parameters. I have another index in the array like this
$data['param3'] = $_SESSION['param3'];

this can be reproduces when I add "\x99\x9C%" to the session.

Answer (score 0):

The string you submit to json_encode function must be a utf-8 encoded string. You can fix this error as below

```
 echo json_encode(utf8_encode($data));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Thanga I fixed this issue with changing the code like this $param1 = urlencode(mb_convert_encoding($param1, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')). But I need to test this and reproduce it in either live or local. I tried  using different characters but could not reproduce yet.